# Dynamic Time Warping: Why does a Sakoe-Chiba band take much more time to calculate than no window?

Tags: time-series, distance-functions, dynamic-time-warping

I'm using dynamic time warping to calculate a distance matrix for a set of about 25 multivariate time series. Each individual time series has over 1000 timestamps, and they are all the same length. When I use a Sakoe-Chiba window of 50, it averages 3.78 seconds to calculate the distance between two multivariate time series.

When I use a Sakoe-Chiba window of 10, it averages 3.32 seconds. As expected, the smaller window took less time, since there are fewer local and cumulative distances to calculate. However, if I use no window at all, it averages 0.29 seconds. That's over 10 times faster, but this makes no sense to me since it's essentially using the largest possible window. Why is this happening? What am I misunderstanding here?

If it matters, I'm using the dtw-python package.

Answer (score 0):

This difference in performance is most likely due to the way the package implements the windowing functions. It does this by creating a matrix the same size as the distance matrix that has 1's in valid positions for the warping path and 0's elsewhere. If you are not using a windowing function, that's simply a matrix of 1's, which is fast to create. With a windowing function it firstly creates a boolean matrix, then converts that to an integer matrix, which is a lot more work.

Comment: Please see 
https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6304/my-upvoting-policy, 
when you find a question sufficiently clear to 
write an answer, consider to upvote the question!